# select adjacent coordinates in a list and return a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, coordinates

I have a list of tuple which contains coordinates X and Y. The program has to return a list of adjacent coordinates (X+1,Y or X,Y+1) without libraries
exemple:

```
list = [(1, 30), (1, 31), (1, 32), (1, 33), (2, 30), (2, 31), (2, 32), (2, 33),
        (3, 30), (3, 31), (3, 32), (3, 33), (3, 45), (3, 48), (4, 30), (4, 31),
        (4, 32), (4, 33), (5, 30), (5, 31), (5, 32), (5, 33), (5, 66), (5, 89),
        (6, 34), (6, 35), (6, 36), (6, 37), (6, 38), (6, 39), (7, 30), (7, 31),
        (7, 32)]

new_list = [(1, 30), (1, 31), (1, 32), (1, 33), (2, 30), (2, 31), (2, 32),
            (2, 33), (3, 30), (3, 31), (3, 32), (3, 33), (4, 30), (4, 31),
            (4, 32), (4, 33), (5, 30), (5, 31), (5, 32), (5, 33)]
```

My code:

```
`def MyFunction(newList, List):
    newList.append(List[0])
    List.remove(List[0])
    if (List[0][0],List[0][1]+1) in List:
        newList.append((List[0][0],List[0][1]+1))
        MyFunction(newList, List)
    elif (List[0][0]+1,List[0][1]) in List:
        newList.append((List[0][0]+1,List[0][1]))
        MyFunction(newList, List)
    return

List=[(1, 30), (1, 31), (1, 32), (1, 33), (1, 34), (1, 35), (1, 36), (1, 37), (1, 38), (1, 39), (2, 30), (2, 31), (2, 32), (2, 33), (2, 34), (2, 35), (2, 36), (2, 37), (2, 38), (2, 39), (3, 30), (3, 31), (3, 32), (3, 33), (3, 34), (3, 35), (3, 36), (3, 37), (3, 38), (3, 39), (4, 30), (4, 31), (4, 32), (4, 33), (4, 34), (4, 35), (4, 36), (4, 37), (4, 38), (4, 39), (5, 30), (5, 31), (5, 32), (5, 33), (5, 34), (5, 35), (5, 36), (5, 37), (5, 38), (5, 39), (6, 30), (6, 31), (6, 32), (6, 33), (6, 34), (6, 35), (6, 36), (6, 37), (6, 38), (6, 39), (7, 30), (7, 31), (7, 32), (7, 33), (7, 34), (7, 35), (7, 36), (7, 37), (7, 38), (7, 39), (8, 30), (8, 31), (8, 32), (8, 33), (8, 34), (8, 35), (8, 36), (8, 37), (8, 38), (8, 39), (9, 30), (9, 31), (9, 32), (9, 33), (9, 34), (9, 35), (9, 36), (9, 37), (9, 38), (9, 39), (10, 10), (10, 11), (10, 12), (10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 15), (10, 16), (10, 17), (10, 18), (10, 19), (10, 30), (10, 31), (10, 32), (10, 33), (10, 34), (10, 35), (10, 36), (10, 37), (10, 38), (10, 39), (10, 50), (10, 51), (10, 52), (10, 53)]
My_output=[(1, 30), (1, 32), (1, 31), (1, 33), (1, 32), (1, 34), (1, 33), (1, 35), (1, 34), (1, 36), (1, 35), (1, 37), (1, 36), (1, 38), (1, 37), (1, 39), (1, 38), (2, 39), (1, 39), (2, 31), (2, 30), (2, 32), (2, 31), (2, 33), (2, 32), (2, 34), (2, 33), (2, 35), (2, 34), (2, 36), (2, 35), (2, 37), (2, 36), (2, 38), (2, 37), (2, 39), (2, 38), (3, 39), (2, 39), (3, 31), (3, 30), (3, 32), (3, 31), (3, 33), (3, 32), (3, 34), (3, 33), (3, 35), (3, 34), (3, 36), (3, 35), (3, 37), (3, 36), (3, 38), (3, 37), (3, 39), (3, 38), (4, 39), (3, 39), (4, 31), (4, 30), (4, 32), (4, 31), (4, 33), (4, 32), (4, 34), (4, 33), (4, 35), (4, 34), (4, 36), (4, 35), (4, 37), (4, 36), (4, 38), (4, 37), (4, 39), (4, 38), (5, 39), (4, 39), (5, 31), (5, 30), (5, 32), (5, 31), (5, 33), (5, 32), (5, 34), (5, 33), (5, 35), (5, 34), (5, 36), (5, 35), (5, 37), (5, 36), (5, 38), (5, 37), (5, 39), (5, 38), (6, 39), (5, 39), (6, 31), (6, 30), (6, 32), (6, 31), (6, 33), (6, 32), (6, 34), (6, 33), (6, 35), (6, 34), (6, 36), (6, 35), (6, 37), (6, 36), (6, 38), (6, 37), (6, 39), (6, 38), (7, 39), (6, 39), (7, 31), (7, 30), (7, 32), (7, 31), (7, 33), (7, 32), (7, 34), (7, 33), (7, 35), (7, 34), (7, 36), (7, 35), (7, 37), (7, 36), (7, 38), (7, 37), (7, 39), (7, 38), (8, 39), (7, 39), (8, 31), (8, 30), (8, 32), (8, 31), (8, 33), (8, 32), (8, 34), (8, 33), (8, 35), (8, 34), (8, 36), (8, 35), (8, 37), (8, 36), (8, 38), (8, 37), (8, 39), (8, 38), (9, 39), (8, 39), (9, 31), (9, 30), (9, 32), (9, 31), (9, 33), (9, 32), (9, 34), (9, 33), (9, 35), (9, 34), (9, 36), (9, 35), (9, 37), (9, 36), (9, 38), (9, 37), (9, 39), (9, 38), (10, 39), (9, 39), (10, 11), (10, 10), (10, 12), (10, 11), (10, 13), (10, 12), (10, 14), (10, 13), (10, 15), (10, 14), (10, 16), (10, 15), (10, 17), (10, 16), (10, 18), (10, 17), (10, 19), (10, 18)]
expected_output=[(1, 30), (1, 32), (1, 31), (1, 33), (1, 32), (1, 34), (1, 33), (1, 35), (1, 34), (1, 36), (1, 37), (1, 38), (1, 39), (2, 30), (2, 31), (2, 32), (2, 33), (2, 34), (2, 35), (2, 36), (2, 37), (2, 38), (2, 39), (3, 30), (3, 31), (3, 32), (3, 33), (3, 34), (3, 35), (3, 36), (3, 37), (3, 38), (3, 39), (4, 30), (4, 31), (4, 32), (4, 33), (4, 34), (4, 35), (4, 36), (4, 37), (4, 38), (4, 39), (5, 30), (4, 31), (5, 32), (5, 33), (5, 34), (5, 35), (5, 36), (5, 37), (5, 38), (5, 39), (6, 30), (5, 31), (6, 32), (6, 33), (6, 34), (6, 35), (6, 36), (6, 37), (6, 38), (6, 39), (7, 30), (6, 31), (7, 32), (7, 33), (7, 34), (7, 35), (7, 36), (7, 37), (7, 38), (7, 39), (8, 30), (8, 31), (8, 32), (8, 33), (8, 34), (8, 35), (8, 36), (8, 37), (8, 38), (8, 39), (9, 39), (9, 31), (9, 30), (9, 32), (9, 31), (9, 33), (9, 32), (9, 34), (9, 33), (9, 35), (9, 34), (9, 36), (9, 35), (9, 37), (9, 36), (9, 38), (9, 39), (10, 30), (10, 31), (10, 32), (10, 33), (10, 34), (10, 35), (10, 36), (10, 37), (10, 38), (10, 39)]
```

Comment: The problem statement doesn't make sense to me. In addition to showing what you've tried, I think you need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = []

# get coordinates one by one.
for (x,y) in list1:
    # search adjacent coordinates of (x, y)
    adjacent_of_x_y = [(xx, yy) for (xx, yy) in list1 if abs(x-xx)<=1 and abs(y-yy)<=1 and x != xx and y != yy]
    print(f'Adjacent coordinates for ({x},{y}):')
    print(adjacent_of_x_y)
```